# Why can we create class objects in a list comprehension without assigning each instance to a variable?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Once you create a class, you must instantiate to use it by doing `variable = Class()`, then you can use the class instance. In that case, why does this work?

```
one = [LinkedList() for thing in range(size)]
```

Here, we are creating a list of size `size` called `one` which is made up of a number of `LinkedList` class instances. How is this possible, since none of the `LinkedList` class instances have been assigned to a variable/instantiated in the way of `variable = Class()`?

Comment: "you must instantiate to use it by doing `variable = Class()`" What makes you think that? Since this appears to be the source for your misconception, it's hard to meaningfully clear it up other than disagreeing.

Answer (score 1):

> Once you create a class, you must instantiate to use it by doing `variable = Class()`

There are two steps in this process:

1. The expression `Class()` creates an object.
2. The assignment `variable = ...` creates a reference to the object so that you can refer to it by the given name.

Only step 1 is needed to actually *create* the object. If you don't create a reference to it (e.g. as in step 2) you won't be able to *use* it later and it will eventually be destroyed again by the garbage collector.

But there are other ways to create references to objects, for example lists.

If an object is in a list, you don't refer to it by name, but by list indexing, or by iteration.

Comment: I think if it will only "eventually" be destroyed again by the garbage collector, for example because it keeps a reference to itself, then you might still be able to find and use it. [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZU87DsIwDN1zCjO1laAzQmLiFExRSZ0SVJwocaRyFpYucCA2bkPTgFSJNzz5o2e_d3-6G58tjeMjst5s3y9zddYzdEoI1TchwCHxTsCEFjVIaciwlGXAXld5npDaOhHs53oh8Oj8v8AjR09QHG0EbSO1cMVVIcT8r6yE0NbDAIYmL3WHLO3pgoqnVb5hNJhgKHBDCsthnY0uHjhviMuhysm-AX9BPw).

Answer (score -2):

> Once you create a class, you must instantiate to use it by doing
> `variable = Class()`

This is not true, consider that `python` has [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator, which allows you to create methods, which might be used without creating instance of class, consider following simple example

```
class Klass:
    @classmethod
    def whoami(cls):
        return cls.__name__
print(Klass.whoami())
```

gives output

```
Klass
```